# Json.Net Deserialize Returning Nulls

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I'm using the Petfinder API and trying to return a root object in my C# code. I used the Json class generator to generate the classes, but the Deserialize function is returning nulls.

This is my C# code:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://api.petfinder.com/shelter.getPets?format=json&key=<key>&id=<id>");
            Petfinder deserializedPet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Petfinder>(json);

        }
```

The Petfinder object is defined as:

```
internal class Petfinder
{

    [JsonProperty("@xmlns:xsi")]
    public string XmlnsXsi { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lastOffset")]
    public LastOffset LastOffset { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pets")]
    public Pets Pets { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("header")]
    public Header Header { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation")]
    public string XsiNoNamespaceSchemaLocation { get; set; }
}
```

The first few lines of the json string is as follows:

{"@encoding":"iso-8859-1","@version":"1.0","petfinder":{"@xmlns:xsi":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance","lastOffset":{"$t":"25"},"pets":{"pet":[{"options":{"option":[{"$t":"hasShots"},{"$t":"altered"},{"$t":"housetrained"}]},"breeds":{"breed":{"$t":"Domestic Medium Hair"}},"shelterPetId":{},"status":{"$t":"A"},"name":{"$t":"Jasmine"},...

If that helps at all.

I'm a newbie to json.net. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class is wrong, take a look at the output from [json2csharp.com](http://www.json2csharp.com) for the example json you provided. Obviously the `__invalid_name_$t` needs to be manually fixed and the mapped using `[JsonProperty]`.

```
public class LastOffset
{
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Option
{
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Options
{
    public List<Option> option { get; set; }
}

public class Breed
{
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Breeds
{
    public Breed breed { get; set; }
}

public class ShelterPetId
{
}

public class Status
{
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Name
{
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Pet
{
    public Options options { get; set; }
    public Breeds breeds { get; set; }
    public ShelterPetId shelterPetId { get; set; }
    public Status status { get; set; }
    public Name name { get; set; }
}

public class Pets
{
    public List<Pet> pet { get; set; }
}

public class Petfinder
{
    public string __invalid_name__@xmlns:xsi { get; set; }
    public LastOffset lastOffset { get; set; }
    public Pets pets { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string __invalid_name__@encoding { get; set; }    
    public string __invalid_name__@version { get; set; }
    public Petfinder petfinder { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So I rename those odd names and then reference RootObject in the deserialize command?

Comment: Getting closer to deserializing but values in the new object are still null. It's probably something to do with how they're named so I'll mark your solution as fixed (and definitely save the json mapping site for future!). Thanks.

Comment: This is the class after my edits but still generating nulls.??

Comment: @jallen could you please update your question with your new class definitions? Simply append them to the bottom of the question with something like "Updated:"

Comment: Hi Pete! I abandoned the json output and went with XML and it works perfectly. Thanks!